# ggplot2 multi-histogram graph plotting only single histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(d,aes(x= `Log Number`)) + 
    geom_histogram(data=subset(d,state == 'c'),fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_histogram(data=subset(d,state == 'l'),fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_histogram(data=subset(d,state == 't'),fill = "green", alpha = 0.2)
```

d is a dataset only contain two columns log number which is a long list of number, state which is a factor contain 3 levels-c,l,t
 i tried to use it to plot a overlapping histogram but it just return a single one. Thanks

[image: the graph it produced]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I don't know, I think your data is wrong. Worked for me:

```
lon <- log( rnorm(1000,exp(6) ))
state <- sample(c("c","l","t"),1000,replace=T)
d <- data.frame(lon,state)
names(d) <- c("Log Number","state")
head(d)
```

yields the following data:

```
  Log Number state
1   5.999955     t
2   5.997907     c
3   6.002452     l
4   5.994471     l
5   5.997306     l
6   6.000798     t
```

And then the plot:

```
ggplot(d,aes(x= `Log Number`)) + 
  geom_histogram(data=subset(d,state == 'c'),fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(d,state == 'l'),fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(d,state == 't'),fill = "green", alpha = 0.2)
```

looks like this:
[image]

Comment: and, excuse me, could you tell me how to add a legend for this

Comment: Hmm, looking at that now. Not so easy.

Answer (score 2):

You want to fill by status

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = `Log Number`, fill = state)) + geom_histogram()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion on my generated data. Looks wrong. Like a tricolor flag.

Comment: Interestingly your solution kind of works if I substitute backticks instead of single quotes in Log Number. So `Log Number` (with backtics) instead of `'Log Number'`. Not quite what the OP wanted, but way closer. WTH does that do?